# Programmatically check ChexBox in CardView

Tags: android

I Have RecyclerView with some CardViews. There is TextView and CheckBox in each CardView. When user tap CardView need to check CheckBox in this CardView. I set ClickListner on my RecyclerView:

```
     rv.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(getActivity(),
 rv, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {

                }        
            }));
```

What to do next?

Comment: view.findViewById(R.id.yiur_check_box_id).setChecked(true); hope this works